# Prisma / NestJS : Error: Cannot find module 'src/prisma/prisma.module.js' Require stack:

Tags: node.js, typescript, compilation, nestjs, prisma

I'm working on a project with Prisma and NestJS.

The error :

```
Error : Cannot find module 'src/prisma/prisma.module.js'
Require stack: - /home/cedric/Bureau/programmation/project_bank/project/dist/auth/auth.module.js
- /home/cedric/Bureau/programmation/project_bank/project/dist/app.module.js
- /home/cedric/Bureau/programmation/project_bank/project/dist/main.js
```

occured when I tried to add a `@Global` Decorator in my PrismaModule. I directly Ctrl+Z but the error's still there.

I think it's a compilation problem but don't know how to revert it.

Here is my code :
prisma.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';

@Module({
  providers: [PrismaService],
  exports: [PrismaService],
})
export class PrismaModule {}
```

prisma.service.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';

describe('PrismaService', () => {
  let service: PrismaService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [PrismaService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<PrismaService>(PrismaService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

The module in which i'd like to use PrismaModule :

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PrismaModule } from "src/prisma/prisma.module.js";
import { PrismaService } from "src/prisma/prisma.service.js";
import { AuthController } from "./auth.controller.js";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service.js";

@Module({
    imports: [PrismaModule],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [AuthService, PrismaService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

My app.module.ts :

```
import { CustomersModule } from './customers/customers.module';
import { PrismaModule } from './prisma/prisma.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule, CustomersModule, PrismaModule, ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was quite simple but I can't find it anywhere.

In this code, the PrismaModule is imported too many times.

In the AuthModule, we can see that the PrismaService is once imported with `providers: [AuthService, PrismaService]` and once imported inside the PrismaModule in `imports: [PrismaModule]`

So, the correct code should be :

auth.module.ts:

```
@Module({
    imports: [PrismaModule],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [AuthService]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has a similar problem

> Error: Cannot find module ...

try changing absolute links (ts mapping via baseUrl) to relative ones.
For example, from

```
src/database/prisma.service
```

to

```
../../database/prisma.service
```